# How to display a dialog with warning message from controller in Odoo?

Tags: odoo

Is it possible to display a warning message when overriding a controller function? This is the code I have:

```
raise Warning(_('Entered Quantity is greater than quantity on source.'))
return super(CheckCart, self).cart(**post)
```

I want to render the cart template but also raise a Warning, but I get the following:

> 500: Internal Server Error
>   Error  Error message:  ('Entered Quantity is greater than quantity on
>   source.', '')
>
> Traceback

Without anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Controller File.**

```
request.render("custom_module_name.redirect_fail_page", {})
```

**XML File.**

```
<template id="redirect_fail_page" name="Failure Code Page">
    <div>
          <span>Failed</span>
    </div>
    <script>
        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.href = '/';
        }, 1100)
    </script>
</template>
```

Here you can use **request.render**

Comment: I'm trying to render the existing cart template, is there a way to add this dialog to the existing template without directly modifying it?

Comment: yes just pass the existing template id as I template id after the name of custom_module_name.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this way,
Called the **Json Controller** was based on logic **return the value** and on the **js** check with the value is satisfied then with **Dialog** you can **raise the warning**.

On Py File,

```
@http.route(['/custom/url'], type='json', auth="public", website=True)
def checkout_custom(self, **post):
# Logic Based on the that return True/False.
```

On JS File,

```
var ajax = require('web.ajax');
var Dialog = require('web.Dialog');
ajax.jsonRpc("/custom/url", 'call', {}).then(function(data) {
    if (data) {
        var dialog = new Dialog(this, {
        size: 'medium',
        $content: _t("<div style='font-size:14px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;'>Warning Message.</div>"),
        buttons: [{
            text: _t('Ok'),
            classes: "btn-primary",
            close: true
        }],
    }).open();
} else {
    // Process
}});
```

Thanks